# Ideal of $V(Z-XY,Y^2+XZ-X^2)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, macaulay2

> Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, not necessarily of characteristic $0$. I’m trying to compute the ideal of $C=V(Z-XY,Y^2+XZ-X^2)$ over $k$.

Here is what I have tried so far:

We have $$C=V(Z-XY,Y^2+X^2Y-X^2)=V(Z-XY,Y^2+X^2(Y-1))$$

Let $J=(Z-XY,Y^2+X^2(Y-1))$. According to Macaulay2, at least over $\mathbb{Q}$ we have
$$\sqrt{J}=J$$

In fact, it tells me that $J$ is prime over $\mathbb{Q}$, and I imagine this is true in the general case, but I’m struggling to show it. I can prove that both polynomials are irreducible over $k$, but not much else about the ideal.

I’ve also tried showing that $I(C)=J$ directly, and I think I can prove that we can write any $F\in k[X,Y,Z]$ as
$$F=A_1(X)+YA_2(X)+[Y^2+X^2(Y-1)]B_1(X,Y)+[Z-XY]B_2(X,Y,Z)$$
But I’m struggling then to show that $F\in I(C)$ implies $A_1(X),A_2(X)=0$.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you specified what you are using when you say "Macaulay2"

Comment: It's a computer algebra software for commutative algebra and algebraic geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $k[x,y,z]/(z-xy) \cong k[u,v]$, the polynomial ring in two independent variables, by $x\mapsto u$, $y\mapsto v$ and $z\mapsto uv$. Under this isomorphism, $J$ maps to the ideal $I = (v^2+u^2v-u^2)\subset k[u,v]$. Now, if you show that $v^2+u^2v-u^2$ is irreducible in $k[u,v]$, then your ring is isomorphic to $k[u,v]/(v^2+u^2v-u^2)$, which is an integral domain. This proves that your ideal is prime and thus radical. We are using the Nullstellensatz to say that $I(V(J)) = \sqrt{J} = J$.